# jQuery beforeunload event not firing on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

I have a backbone app, and I want to alert the user before navigating away with unsaved changes. I have an event to do so:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    var status = {
        unsavedEdits: false
    };

    Backbone.trigger('producerApp:navigate', status);
    if (status.unsavedEdits) {
        return status.msg || 'There are unsaved edits. Continuing will discard these edits.';
    }
});
```

The problem is that this is not being fired in Chrome when clicking the back button. I have read nothing that suggests this should be the case. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/IP16dJClLmFYbSfgf76m/ it seems the event is not fired when back button does not take you away from the page (and hence no unload is going to happen).

Comment: That appears to be the issue. We are not navigating away from the page, but loading it with different URL parameters

Comment: are you expecting `Backbone.trigger` or handler of `producerApp:navigate` event to modify value of `status.unsavedEdits` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    var status = {
      unsavedEdits: true
    };

    if (status.unsavedEdits) {
      return 'There are unsaved edits. Continuing will discard these edits.';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think the event is **onbeforeunload**

Use this. Tried on my machine. It worked.

Comment: onbeforeunload does not fire either

Comment: Maybe it is something else in the code then, because onbeforeunload also does not work, and if I put a breakpoint in the code it is never hit. I will have to look into it more I guess.

Comment: The comment to the question seems to be the answer. The code above fires, but only when I navigate away from the page and not when I update the URL parameters of the same page

Comment: I tried refreshing, adding get parameters and also back button. It works

Comment: Now I have added the working snippet. Just run it again and it will pop up

Answer (score 2):

This code should work on the back button as well, as long as there is an initial interaction with the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
return "are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

This is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: This is a complete answer. The addition: "(...) as long as there is an initial interaction (...)" is essential.